# Manually spilt Hbase region using Hbase shell

Tags: hbase

We are facing HBase region hot spotting. All writes are redirected to one region server as a result certain maps are taking lot of time. I want manually spilt the region using HBase shell but could find any example.

I saw the syntax spilt 'regionname', spilt key.

But I am not able to find the spilt key since row key are random serial number.

What is best optimize way to spilt the region server.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for salting which means adding random prefix values to your rowkeys such a way all the rowkeys are not in serial order.

> example:
>
> > rowkey in serial order
> >
> > 2016_1201
> >
> > 2016_1202
> >
> > 2016_1204
> >
> > 2016_1204
> >
> > after salting
> >
> > a_2016_1201
> >
> > b_2016_1202
> >
> > c_2016_1204
> >
> > d_2016_1204

[reference Link](https://sematext.com/blog/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/)

[hbase site - Section 35.1](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#rowkey.design)

Answer (score 0):

Hashing/randomPrefix + salting is generally recommended for writing in Hbase. If your keys are already randomly generated and you know the prefix range (Ex- 000 to FFF in-case of Hex) then you can use 777 as splitKey for dividing single region into 2. Generally it is recommended to pre-split your hbase table according to expected load-size to avoid hot-spotting.